# Which is the least expensive aggregate function in the absence of ANY()

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I usally use MAX() or MIN() if a DBMS hasn't an ANY() aggregate function.

Is there something less expensive in mySQL and MS-SQL?

Comment: why do not exists an ANY() aggregate function?

Comment: Why would an ANY() aggregate function exist?  What would its specification be?

Comment: What do you mean with `ANY()`? It should return one random row?

Comment: `any(expresion)` : returns any value of expresion within the group. in order to have good performance with trivial dependant columns in cases where all are the same or just any is good enaugh

Comment: No ANY aggregate in ANSI-92 SQL http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: @ypercube: the less expensive for the DBMS

Comment: SQL Server has `first()` and `last()` for "don't-care" fields in grouped queries. MySQL doesn't require you to do anything to get non-aggregated fields in grouped queries, just use the fieldname as you would in any other select.

Comment: @Mark B: I know them on Access but not on SQL server, I didn't know the MySQL way, I have just learned. Thanks

Comment: @LuisSiquot - [See also my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753319/sql-server-pick-random-or-first-value-with-aggregation/7753492#7753492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does **not need** an ANY() aggregate.

if I do a

```
SELECT field1, field2, SUM(field3) FROM table1 
GROUP BY field2
```

Microsofts T-SQL will complain but

MySQL will just silently execute

```
SELECT whatever(field1), field2, SUM(....
```

Which of course is way faster than `SELECT max(field1), field2, SUM(.... GROUP BY field2`

MySQL supports `ANY`, but `SELECT ANY(field1) ...` doesn't work because `ANY` is an operator similar to `IN` and `ALL`.
see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

*I love MySQL*

Comment: Ambiguious and not explicit = dangerous.

Comment: @gbn, many tools give you a gun to shoot with, that's why you need to know your tool, so you don't shoot yourself in the foot. Whether guns kill people or people kill people is another discussion entirely.

Comment: @Johan Great!! I have seen SELECT field1, field2, SUM(field3) FROM table1 
GROUP BY field2, field1 ... but field 1 is reudunat as it is field2 dependant.  I think it is worst than min(field1) also

Comment: Poor analogy: not comparable. In this situation I see no need to have the RDBMS guess a column on my behalf. *Only* MySQL has this ambiguity too: SQL Server, Sybase, Oracle, PostGres **do not**. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5986127/27535

Comment: @gbn, personally I think the any() keyword is the better solution, looking at the docs MySQL does support it, but because sooo many MySQL queries depend on the old `dangerous` behavior it's not going to go away. The whole idiology of MySQL is to be as forgiving as possible, for some things this makes it the **right tool for the job** TM, for other jobs not. Know your tools and choose wisely.

Comment: What a fantastic coinage, and very appropriate: *idiology*, as in idio[tic] [ideo]logy, as in "the idiology of MySQL". I'll remember that one. (The correct spelling is *ideology*, btw.)

Comment: @Johan - To carry your firearms analogy to it's conclusion - Quality guns (all other RDBMS) give you a safety switch to prevent accidental firing.  MYSQL gives you a hair trigger and overloaded ammunition to make it much easier to hurt yourself.

Comment: Strikes me as error prone. In DBs that handle windowing, you can get this behavior in a more obvious manner.

Comment: @JNK, @Johan, @Andrew Lazarus: An example of why this MySQL behaviour is stupid http://stackoverflow.com/q/6642241/27535

Comment: @gbn - I didn't require any convincing, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @JNK: I know from above, but some ammunition in case of bunfight... ;-)

Comment: As a note, this is no longer the case with default connection settings, particularly under MySQL Workbench - this is controlled by `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`.  Issuing such a query will show the following: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #NUMBER of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'TABLE.COLUMN' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* ANY aggregate in [ANSI SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

There *is* the ANY qualifier to match SOME and ALL

- [TSQL - SOME | ANY why are they same with different names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1383988/27535) (SO)
- [ALL, ANY, and SOME: The Three Stooges](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/all-any-and-some-the-three-stooges/) (SQL Server Pedia)

MIN and MAX are proper aggregates... completely unrelated and shouldn't be compared

Edit:

Only MySQL has this ambiguity of an "ANY" aggregate: SQL Server, Sybase, Oracle, PostGres do not. See [Do all columns in a SELECT list have to appear in a GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5986127/27535)

Comment: i have selected a wrong name to "my aggregate" function. but I mean a way to have less expensive alternative of max() or min() if it exists

Comment: great!! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986127/do-all-columns-in-a-select-list-have-to-appear-in-a-group-by-clause)

Comment: [SQL Server does have an `ANY` aggregate](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/02/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.aspx)

Comment: @gbn - I've no idea if there would be any benefit to rewriting a query to get it though. Might be some minor reduction in CPU time potentially as it doesn't have to do any comparisons?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I'd say it is an internal optimisation to deal with such cases as this above. If usable directly, it'd cause confusion like the MySQL group by nonsense

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate as of 2015 - [see this update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67836358/2738164) for MySQL 5.7+.

Answer (score 1):

MIN and MAX are equally (in)expensive.

Comment: i know, but is there other less expensive?

Comment: @Luis - If the field is indexed, no.  `MIN` and `MAX` on an indexed field just go to the first or last entry in the index.

Comment: @JNK: but MIN() or MAX() doesn't?

Comment: @Parkyprg: No, `MIN` and `MAX` will use the index (if there is one).

Comment: @JNK - That is only true if you are getting a single `MAX` rather than using `GROUP BY`. If you are doing a `GROUP BY` even if an index exists on `group_column,aggregated_column` it won't skip to the next group. [so for some cardinalities a recursive CTE can be better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753319/sql-server-pick-random-or-first-value-with-aggregation/7753492#7753492)

Comment: @MartinSmith - If I have to do a lot of aggregation, I normally do an index on `(GroupField) INCLUDE (Aggregates)`, but yes this could be different based on aggregation

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 5.7 (released October 2015), there is actually a function for this!  `any_value(col)` explicitly meets this need - see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) for details.

However, it's important to note that it still appears to not guarantee a short-circuit and may still perform a full scan, so the goal of higher efficiency may not be met.  If MySQL is intelligent about it, there is some chance, though testing would be wise.  There are two circumstances in which it may be helpful anyway:

- If the value to be aggregated is particularly large and unindexed, such that any comparisons would be expensive.
- If the intention in the code would be made less clear by leveraging `max` or another placeholder aggregate.  For example, a `max` may imply there was some reason for its existence rather than getting "anything" from the grouping, but `any_value` would explicitly define the intention without additional commenting.

Toy sample:

```
select
col, 
any_value(a.val) as any_val
from (
    select 'blue' as col, 3 as val
    union all
    select 'blue' as col, 2 as val
    union all
    select 'green' as col, 1 as val
) as a
group by col
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine, let's rephrase the original question. Instead of ANY, which is ambiguous and not SQL standard, it would be great if EXISTS-aggregate function was provided.

On several occasions I have used "count(outer.column) > 0" to imitate the "exists(outer.column)", which would be arguably cheaper since counting is discarded anyway.