# How to create algorithm or formula to get the combinations?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

i want to create an algorithm or formula that gives me the following combinations below. I have manually printed out all the combinations for the example containing 4 tables with respective values.

This is not permutation because i need the combinations to always follow the unique format

> Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4   values

So how can i achieve this in SQL script or through C# code (VB.Net code can also work)

Note: the solution contain all the possible 48 combinations i need for my problem.

**Problem**

Table1     Table2     Table3     
Table4
a1             b1           
c1             d1
a2             b2           
c2             d2

a3                            
c3
                                
c4

**Solution**

a1,b1,c1,d1
a1,b1,c1,d2
a1,b1,c2,d1
a1,b1,c2,d2
a1,b1,c3,d1
a1,b1,c3,d2
a1,b1,c4,d1
a1,b1,c4,d2

a1,b2,c1,d1
a1,b2,c1,d2
a1,b2,c2,d1
a1,b2,c2,d2
a1,b2,c3,d1
a1,b2,c3,d2
a1,b2,c4,d1
a1,b2,c4,d2

a2,b1,c1,d1
a2,b1,c1,d2
a2,b1,c2,d1
a2,b1,c2,d2
a2,b1,c3,d1
a2,b1,c3,d2
a2,b1,c4,d1
a2,b1,c4,d2

a2,b2,c1,d1
a2,b2,c1,d2
a2,b2,c2,d1
a2,b2,c2,d2
a2,b2,c3,d1
a2,b2,c3,d2
a2,b2,c4,d1
a2,b2,c4,d2

a3,b1,c1,d1
a3,b1,c1,d2
a3,b1,c2,d1
a3,b1,c2,d2
a3,b1,c3,d1
a3,b1,c3,d2
a3,b1,c4,d1
a3,b1,c4,d2

a3,b2,c1,d1
a3,b2,c1,d2
a3,b2,c2,d1
a3,b2,c2,d2
a3,b2,c3,d1
a3,b2,c3,d2
a3,b2,c4,d1
a3,b2,c4,d2

Comment: @anirudh4444: Two answers below show it can be done. In fact this is a classical use of the set theory that underpins SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```
select *
from
  table1
  cross join table2
  cross join table3
  cross join table4
```

Same thing:

```
select *
from
  table1, table2, table3, table4
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` would also return the full cartesian product

Comment: @Duncan Howe: CROSS APPLY is *not* for this. @GSerg: Your first solution should be CROSS JOIN

Comment: @gbn My bad, for some reason I thought the cross was default if omitted.

Comment: @GSerg: could be on some RDBMS of course, but with .net I assumed SQL Server :-)

Comment: @gbn: Just FYI, there is an RDBMS that treats INNER [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) same as CROSS JOINs. An excerpt from the linked article: `In [the said RDBMS], CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.`

Comment: @Andriy M: Thanks, *another* MySQL ambiguity... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060241/which-is-the-least-expensive-aggregate-function-in-the-absence-of-any/6060419#6060419

Answer (score 4):

Use CROSS JOIN (rather then the usual INNER or LEFT OUTER JOINs)

```
select *
from
  table1
  cross join table2
  cross join table3
  cross join table4
```

or the implied JOIN as per GSerg's answer `...from table1, table2, table3, table4`