# MySQL - Latest Row using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table (table1):

```
ID   INSERTDATE    ISSUE    SOURCE
1    2011-12-01    A        EMAIL
2    2011-12-02    B        POST
3    2011-12-03    C        MEETING
4    2011-12-04    B        INTERNET
```

I would like to get the latest SOURCE for each issue...

```
SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY SOURCE ORDER BY ISSUE ASC
```

Results in

```
ID   INSERTDATE    ISSUE    SOURCE
1    2011-12-01    A        EMAIL
2    2011-12-02    B        POST
3    2011-12-03    C        MEETING
```

But how can I get the following, so that issue B has the latest source?

```
ID   INSERTDATE    ISSUE    SOURCE
1    2011-12-01    A        EMAIL
4    2011-12-04    B        INTERNET
3    2011-12-03    C        MEETING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an aggregate and a self join. 
This is standard SQL without relying on the MySQL group by extensions (which [are rubbish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6060241/27535))

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    ( -- get most recent ID per issue
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID, ISSUE
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ISSUE
    ) t2
    JOIN  -- join back to get the whole row
    table1 t ON t2.MaxID = t.ID
```

Edit, after comment. Assumes one change *per day* only

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    ( -- get most recent INSERTDATE per issue
    SELECT MAX(INSERTDATE) AS MaxINSERTDATE, ISSUE
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ISSUE
    ) t2
    JOIN  -- join back to get the whole row
    table1 t ON t2.MaxINSERTDATE = t.ID
```

Comment: I cant ensure that the highest ID is the latest issue... it has to be determined by the insertdate

Comment: If you have 2 on the same day?

Comment: In my real world problem, it does have a time aswell. I cant detail my real world problem for security reasons ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should order by INSERTDATE (maybe ,ISSUE)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY SOURCE ORDER BY INSERTDATE DESC
```