# PostgreSQL =ANY and IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

Recently I've read [Quantified Comparison Predicates – Some of SQL’s Rarest Species](https://blog.jooq.org/tag/quantified-comparison-predicates/):

> In fact, the SQL standard defines the **IN predicate as being just syntax sugar for the = ANY() quantified comparison predicate.**

```
8.4 <in predicate>

Let RVC be the <row value predicand> and 
let IPV be the <in predicate value>.

The expression  RVC IN IPV
is equivalent to  RVC = ANY IPV
```

Fair enough, based on other answers like: [What is exactly “SOME / ANY” and “IN”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213971) or [Oracle: '= ANY()' vs. 'IN ()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298550/oracle-any-vs-in)
I've assumed that I could use them interchangely.

Now here is my example:

```
select 'match'
where 1 = any( string_to_array('1,2,3', ',')::int[])
-- match

select 'match'
where 1 IN ( string_to_array('1,2,3', ',')::int[])
-- ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
-- HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
-- You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**[DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d5e953788ebf82f57db9744c5f87abf2)**

The question is why the first query is working and the second returns error?

Comment: Arrays are not part of standard SQL.  Postgres interprets that second as saying the "1" is equal to the entire array, not a particular component of it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I know that array is PostgreSQL extension. Could you provide more detailed answer with links to documentation? Maybe with how operator overloading works in presented case.

Comment: `in (scalar list)` and `= any (array)` are valid. `in(array)` is not documented to work. right?..

Comment: docs sate that `in(subquery)` is equal to `= any(subquery)`  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN but `= any(array)` is not equal to `in(array)`, even despite the fact that if `in(scalar list)` has more then one item, planner rewrites it as `=any(array)`, it does not mean `in(array)` would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `IN` (unlike `ANY`) does not accept an *array* as input. Only a *set* (from a subquery) or a *list* of values. Detailed explanation:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer in linked question, I've marked my question as duplicate

Comment: @lad2025: Yes, seems appropriate.